# Script or piece of code to get a quick list of links per page in a website

Tags: scripting, web, reporting

How can I quickly produce a report of a website in the format:

```
Page Name.
- Links within the page

Page Name.
- Links within the page
```

Any programming or scripting language will do.

Although I prefer a solution on Windows, we have all of: Windows, Mac and Linux platforms available in the office.

Just looking for a way to do it without much fanfare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be tools able to do this for you, but it isn't all that hard to put together yourself. One possible solution would be to...

1. Use wget (can be found for Windows) to download all HTML files, and
2. use some xpath tool or grep with regexps to get the title and the links from the pages.

///Jens

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of link analysers that will do exactly that. [Here's](http://www.seochat.com/seo-tools/site-link-analyzer/) the first I found in Google.

For something a little more interesting, Don Syme did a great F# demo in which he wrote a really simple asynch URL processing class. I can't find the exact link, but [here's](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-fsharp-async-intro.aspx) something similar from an F# MVP. You would need to adapt it to pull out links, and recursively follow them if you want nesting.